# Find all video files with a duration in a given interval from commandline

Tags: files, find, video

How can I find all video files with such that the duration is in a specific interval.

For example find all video files with a duration between 20 and 40 minutes.

Comment: It would depend on the video encoding used. You could first guess-estimate some interval on the file size first, and use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) on it.

Comment: The [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) utility could be used on the command line to extract a segment of video. You could build something above that.

Comment: Just use mediainfo command.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mediainfo.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script will do the job for you. It assumes the videos are in a directory (not all over your system).

The script also assumes you have `avprobe` installed, which is part of `avconv`. Should be same syntax as `ffprobe` (part of `ffmpeg`) if you have that instead. If the output from `ffprobe` is different the script will need editing.

The duration is require in seconds however - saves make a calculation.

```
#!/bin/sh

# NOTE: Assumes you have avprobe installed and the full path
# to it is /usr/bin/avprobe - if not, edit.

# Where are the videos?
MASTER="/home/tigger/Videos"
# Duration min in seconds (1200 = 20min)
DUR_MIN="1200"
# Duration max in seconds (2400 = 40min)
DUR_MAX="2400"

# Get a list of files
LIST=`find "$MASTER" -type f`

# In case of a space in file names, split on return
IFS_ORIG=$IFS
IFS="
"

valid="\nList of videos with duration between $DUR_MIN and $DUR_MAX seconds"

# Loop over the file list and probe each file.
for v in $LIST
do
    printf "Checking ${v}\n"
    dur=`/usr/bin/avprobe -v error -show_format_entry duration "${v}"`
    if [ -n $dur ]
    then
        # Convert the float to int
        dur=${dur%.*}
        if [ $dur -ge $DUR_MIN -a $dur -le $DUR_MAX ]
        then
            valid="${valid}\n$v"
        fi
    fi
done

printf "${valid}\n"
exit
```